# How to improve loss reduction?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, regression, loss

I'm trying to predict some continous values depending on gender, annual income and age, with a regression model. My Loss value is too big. I tried googling myself but all i found was to improve hyperparamters(number of units,number of hidden layers,batch_size,learning_rate,epochs). Being a regression,the activation function is 'linear' . What can i do to improve my model?

Here is my try:

```
#IMPORTING DATASETS
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

data1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Cucu\Desktop\Mall_Customers.csv") 
x = data1.iloc [: , 1:-1].values #SEPARATE INDEPENDENT VARIABLES
y = data1.iloc [: , -1].values #SEPARATE DEPENDENT VARIABLES


#ENCODING CATEGORICAL DATA
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
x[: , 0] = le.fit_transform( x[: , 0] )
x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')
 

#LET'S SPLIT INTO TRAIN SET & TEST SET
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(x , y , test_size = 0.2 , random_state = 1 )


#APPLYING FEATURE SCALING
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train[: , 2:] = sc.fit_transform(x_train[: , 2:])
x_test[: , 2:] = sc.transform(x_test[: , 2:])

#BULDING THE ANN
#INITIALZING THE ANN
ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

#ADDING THE INPUT LAYER &THE FIRST HIDDEN LAYER
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
#--units(the number of neurons--hyper-parameter--must be optimized)

#ADDING THE HIDDEN LAYERS
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 30 , activation = 'relu'))


#ADDING THE OUPUT LAYER
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1)) #linear need for regression model and mean_squared_error loss function


rmsprop = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001 , rho = 0.9 , epsilon = 1e-07 , centered = False)
#TRAINING THE ANN
#1)compiling the ann
ann.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop' , loss = 'mean_squared_error' )

#2)training the ann on the training set
ann.fit(x_train , y_train , batch_size = 10 , epochs = 1000)
```

For that model i got :

```
Epoch 1000/1000
160/160 [==============================] - 0s 156us/sample - loss: 235.1505
```

All i found was to adjust hyperparameters and i did that, but i still have too big loss value. **Do i have to still modify them? Is there any else problem in my code?**

Comment: On what ground you consider that 235 is a big value? What is the scale of your dependent variable?

Comment: if you mean on how big is my dataset,it has 200 samples. i didn't scale the dependent variables. i separated independent variables and dependent variables and scaled only independent variables with a standard scaler. if i gave you wrong answers,please give me more explicit question and i will try hard to answer you more correctly.

Comment: I men what is the scale/range of your dependent variable `y` - how big or small are they? This is the first thing to ask before deciding if a given value of MSE is "good" of "bad", because, contrary to metrics like accuracy (in classification), metrics like MSE are real values, and not percentages.

Comment: the range of the dependent variable is between 1 and 100. in my opinion they are not too big.